# Eliminating redundant loads of GOT register?

Tags: c, optimization, gcc, pic

I'm dealing with some code that's getting 70-80% slower when compiled as PIC (position independent code), and looking for ways to alleviate the problem. A big part of the problem is that gcc insists on inserting the following in every single function:

```
call __i686.get_pc_thunk.bx
addl $_GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_,%ebx
```

even if that ends up being 20% of the content of the function. Now, `ebx` is a call-preserved register, and **every** function in the relevant translation unit (source file) is loading it with the address of the GOT, and it's easily detectable that the `static` functions cannot be called from outside the translation unit (their addresses are never taken). So why can't gcc just load `ebx` once at the beginning of the big external-linkage functions, and generate the static-linkage functions so that they assume `ebx` has already been loaded with the address of the GOT? Is there any optimization flag I can use to force gcc to make this obvious and massive optimization, short of turning the inline limits up sky-high so everything gets inlined into the external functions?

Comment: This looks relevant and disappointing: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=23756

Comment: Just because your functions are static it doesn't actually mean they couldn't be passed as function pointers to other compilation units. I wonder if that GOT table addition really slows down those functions so much. Did you actually profile it? And if so, such short functions are good candidates for inlining, which also saved the overhead of creating their stack frame.

Comment: @datenwolf: As I said in the question, their addresses are never taken, so they cannot be passed as function pointers. gcc already makes a number of optimizations (like switching to pass-by-register) for functions that can never be called externally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably no generic cure for this, but you could try to play around with inlining options. I'd guess that `static` functions in a compilation unit don't have too many callers, so the overhead in code replication wouldn't be too bad.

The easiest way to force such things with gcc would be to set an `attribute((always_inline))`. You could play around with a gcc dependent macro to ensure portability.

If you don't want to modify the code (but `static inline` would be good anyhow) you could use the `-finline-limit` option to fine tune that.

Comment: `-O3` made the problem go away at the expense of doubling the file size. No word yet on whether this hurts performance in some callers due to cache issues...

Comment: Hm, I was supposing you had already some level of `-O` switched on. If you are not satisfied with what `-O3` does, you could cherry-pick some of the options that this implies.

Comment: I normally use `-Os`, which tends to produce much smaller code, and roughly the same performance (sometimes up to 10% faster, sometimes up to 10% slower, than `-O3`).

Comment: @R.., so the compiler did what you asked him to do, optimizing for size merely than for speed.

Comment: @Jens: Inserting an extra two (expensive!) instructions in each tiny function is hardly what I'd call optimizing for size. As I said, I don't *want* inlining, it's just a simple workaround for the problem. What I want is for gcc to stop generating redundant and expensive instructions. :-)

Comment: Checked off as accepted. This seems to be the only workaround for now. http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html documents for `visibility("internal")` that it allows gcc to optimize out loading the PIC register, but `visibility` is not valid with `static` functions, which (as long as their address is not taken) should already be in a class as strict as `internal` anyway. So it seems to just be a gcc bug/limitation. :-(

Answer (score 1):

Not really a solution, but: if the functions in question do not reference file-scope variables, you could put them all together in a single translation unit and compile it without -fPIC flag. Then you link them together with other files in the final SO as usual.

Comment: If they didn't access variables of static storage duration, the GOT register wouldn't get loaded in the first place. The problem is that they do, and must.

Comment: How about packing all globals into a struct and passing a pointer to the struct as function parameter? Then the GOT won't be computed.

Comment: Adding +1 - this is actually a useful idea, but not very applicable to my problem since the function is dealing with both external and static global state (the former in a read-only way, the latter read-write), and by the time I change all these small functions to pass two extra pointers to them, I think the overhead I've added will be as bad as the PIC register loading.