# How to force GCC to not include call to get_pc_thunk when not needed

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, linker

I am writing code that will be compiled (using gcc, targeting Android x86) and then processed by another program. that program has limits on its input such as that the code cannot make indirect calls or reference globals. To enforce this in PIC/PIE code the tool errors on calls to get_pc_thunk (or any function that just reads the top of the stack and returns)

I have my code in a state where it should meet these requirements. All functions are linked in and can be called by offset after linking. but GCC leaves a call to get_pc_thunk in my function even though it is not used.

my code is (test.c):

```
unsigned long long API test(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b)
{
   return a / b;
}
```

to build this I use:

```
gcc.exe -o test.o -fno-stack-protector test.c -c -O0

gcc.exe -o libtest.so -m32 -static -static-libgcc -nostartfiles -shared test.o
```

I get out:

```
000001d8 <test>:
 1d8:   55                      push   ebp
 1d9:   89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
 1db:   53                      push   ebx
 1dc:   8d 64 24 dc             lea    esp,[esp-0x24]
 1e0:   e8 45 00 00 00          call   22a <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>
 1e5:   81 c3 0f 1e 00 00       add    ebx,0x1e0f
 1eb:   8b 45 08                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8]
 1ee:   89 45 f0                mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x10],eax
 1f1:   8b 45 0c                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
 1f4:   89 45 f4                mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc],eax
 1f7:   8b 45 10                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x10]
 1fa:   89 45 e8                mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x18],eax
 1fd:   8b 45 14                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp+0x14]
 200:   89 45 ec                mov    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x14],eax
 203:   8b 45 e8                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x18]
 206:   8b 55 ec                mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x14]
 209:   89 44 24 08             mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x8],eax
 20d:   89 54 24 0c             mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0xc],edx
 211:   8b 45 f0                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x10]
 214:   8b 55 f4                mov    edx,DWORD PTR [ebp-0xc]
 217:   89 04 24                mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
 21a:   89 54 24 04             mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x4],edx
 21e:   e8 0b 00 00 00          call   22e <__udivdi3>
 223:   8d 64 24 24             lea    esp,[esp+0x24]
 227:   5b                      pop    ebx
 228:   5d                      pop    ebp
 229:   c3                      ret    

0000022a <__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx>:
 22a:   8b 1c 24                mov    ebx,DWORD PTR [esp]
 22d:   c3                      ret    

0000022e <__udivdi3>:
 ...
```

having worked through what is happening I understand that at compile time gcc adds placeholders for the call to get_pc_thunk and __udivdi3 since it does not know at that point where __udivdi3 will be, and it might need to be called via a lookup table. However after linking the get_pc_thunk is no longer needed. I have looked through the linker options and cannot find one that will optimize this call out.

Is there an option to remove this unneeded call in this case?

Comment: did you try? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075178/eliminating-redundant-loads-of-got-register and http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-get-rid-of-__i686-get_pc_thunk-bx-779164/

Comment: yes, and that solves the problem for functions that I write, but it does not solve the problem for functions I call from other libraries. Particularly functions from low level libraries the compiler pulls in for platform support such as __udivdi3 above.

Comment: more research seems to indicate building a static libgcc with visibility hidden could also address this issue, so pointers to that might be sufficient to fix this problem.

Comment: You're at least partly wrong that the call to `__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx` is "not used". It is used in order be able to all `__udivdi3`, which might (as far as the compiler can tell) require going through the PLT.

Comment: @tletnes: That won't help. Symbols in `libgcc.a` always have (and **must** have, to prevent serious ABI bugs) hidden visibility, but the compiler can't see that they do; only the linker can. As far as the compiler knows you might plan to link with shared `libgcc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android NDK versions of gcc there is a -fno-pic option that allows PIC to be disabled for special cases like this.